# How to store value, received in delegate class, inside external one?

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

There is a BLEManager class, that is responsible for scanning, connecting, and receiving data from Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices. Looks like that:

```
class BLEManager: ObservableObject, OtherProtocols {
    private var myCentral: CBCentralManager!
    @Published var data = 0.0

    override init() {
        super.init()

        myCentral = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        myCentral.delegate = self
    }

    // ...some functions that scan, establish connection, etc.

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        // here I receive raw value, handle it and get a data to work with
        
        data = 10.0 // imagine it's the data received from BLE device 
    } 
}
```

Right now the *"data to work with"* is stored inside this class. I'd like to move this data in such a way, so the current class (BLEManager) is responsible for the BLE logic only, and data is stored together with other user data.
Is it possible in Swift?

P.s. I'm pretty new to Swift. Have experience in JS.

**EDITED**

In the current case, BLEmanager receives data from one specific peripheral. The data represents a human weight, to be clear. Other than that, there is a struct with human biometric data (age, height, gender). At the end of the day, biometric data + data from the device (weight) are closely related and are used in the same calculations.

**RESULT**

I was able to implement the Cristik’s approach. The only difference that in my case the subsription happens in a View’s `.onAppear()` modifier and not on class init, as he described. Had troubles with passing a publisher to the class.

Comment: This is certainly possible (and common). It just depends on what you want to hold the data (which is equally true in JS). Is there just one peripheral, and you want something to keep track of "the last value for `data`". Or are there multiple peripherals, and you want each of them to keep track of their own value for `data`? (In either case, you can do this with delegates, notifications, Combine Subjects, closures, or any other "observer" pattern you like. With a clearer use, we can recommend the best tool.)

Comment: @RobNapier expanded the topic with additional information. Hope it provides what's required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to move this data in such a way, so the current class (BLEManager) is responsible for the BLE logic only, and data is stored together with other user data

This is a good mindset, as currently your `BLEManager` breaks the Single Responsibility Principle, i.e. has multiple responsibilities. The `ObservedObject` part is a SwiftUI specific thing, so it makes sense to be extracted out of that class.

Now, implementation-wise, one first step that you could make, is to transform the `data` property to a publisher. This will allow clients to connect to the data stream, and allows you to circulate the publisher instead of the `BLEManager` class, in the rest of your app.

```swift
import Combine

class BLEManager: OtherProtocols {
    // you can use `Error` instead of `Never` if you also want to
    // report errors which make the stream come to an end
    var dataPublisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> { _dataPublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher() }

    private var myCentral: CBCentralManager!

    // hiding/encapsulating the true nature of the publisher
    private var _dataPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

    // ...

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        _dataPublisher.send(10.0) // imagine it's the data received from BLE device 
    }
```

This way anyone who's interested in receiving BLE data simply subscribes to that publisher.

Now, on the receiving side, assuming that you also need an `ObservableObject` for your SwiftUI view, you can write something along of the following:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: Int = 0
    
    init(dataPublisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never>) {
        // automatically updates `data` when new values arrive
        dataPublisher.assign(to: &$data)
    }
}
```

If you don't use SwiftUI (I assumed you do, due to the `ObservableObject` conformance), then you can `sink` to the same publisher in order to receive the data.

---

Either SwiftUI, or UIKit, once you have a `BLEManager` instantiated somewhere, you can hide it from the rest of the app, and still provide the means to subscribe to the BLE data, by circulating the publisher. This also helps with the separation of concerns in the rest of the app.

Comment: Thank you for responding with code samples. Could you please specify, what should be used instead of "_data" in "_data.eraseToAnyPublisher()". The compiler says "_data isn't in scope"
I spent half a day trying to figure out how Combine actually works, in order to understand and fix it myself. But I guess my Swift knowledge isn't enough to clearly understand official documentation.
BTW, the compiler also says that the "lazy" can't be used on computed property

Comment: @NeMaksym oops, that was a typo, the `lazy` part was not needed at all, updated the answer and removed it. BTW, this was a regular Swift error, not something related to Combine

Comment: Also `_data` => `_dataPublisher`

Comment: Thanks, for the quick reply.  
Could you please correct me if I'm wrong? 
1. First, we create a publisher
2. Then, trigger the "send()" method on the publisher and put some data in it
3. Last, we subscribe to our publisher (it's actually a place where we receive data updates)

Comment: In `var dataPublisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> { _dataPublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher() }` we create a computed property that triggers some publisher method. But who and when requests this computed property?

Comment: @NeMaksym yes, more or less this is the flow. `PassthroughSubject` is a special kind of publisher, in the sense that it's told from the outside when to emit data, via the `send()` method, and this is why we need to protect it within the manager.

Comment: @NeMaksym the property is requested by anyone who wants to access the Bluetooth data.

Comment: Ah, I got it. we trigger it in the ViewModel's `init`. But how do we get it there as init argument? I mean `ViewModel` class is written by us. How does it know about the publisher's existence and exact computer property name?

Comment: Oh, sorry, maybe it`s my fault. Do we just pass it there when initializing the class?

Comment: @NeMaksym yes, once you ask the `BLEManager` for that publisher, you can pass it to initializers of other classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to connect to a single device, I would keep this very simple, and let BLEManager pass this data to a delegate as it comes in. The delegate would then be responsible for deciding what to do with the data. [Swift by Sundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/delegation-in-swift/) has a nice introduction to delegates if you're not familiar with the pattern.

You'd make a separate object, a "DataManager" or whatever you'd like to call it, and it would be the delegate to the BLEManager (and would own the BLEManager). Whenever new data comes in, call methods like `bleManager(_:didReceiveWeight:)` or `bleManager(_:didReceiveBiometricData:)`.

This will split up the process of getting data from the device from managing that data and performing computations, which I think is a worthy goal.

If this is a "real" project, and you're just starting, I highly recommend this pattern. It's well understood, there are dozens of blog posts about it going back many years. It's easy to understand and implement. The only pattern that's even *easier* to implement is to post [Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter#), from BLEManager.

On the other hand, if this is more of an exploration, and you want to jump into the deep-end and the future of Swift (and limit yourself to iOS 15), you could also look at [AsyncStream](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10058/) to emit new values as they occur into an AsyncSequence. That eventually will likely be the "Swifty" way to do this. But it's a much steeper learning curve, and the tools are not all fully developed yet, and no one *really* knows how to use it yet (not even Apple; it's just too new). If getting in on the ground floor of technology excites you, it's an area that everyone is exploring right now.

But if you just want this thing to work, or you want to focus on learning Swift right now rather than learning "the future of Swift," I'd use a delegate.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed advice. In my case it’s closer to the “exploration” so I will try to implement several approaches you’ve described. P.s. I marked answer of Cristik as correct just because it has code examples that may be useful for anyone who stumble upon this topic.